# implementing SSO concept for php application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

I am new to SSO concept . I have a metadata link from Identity Provider.
Need to send a metadata link back to them . 
How can we build this . 
Web application is created on a PHP framework with username and password login.
Can this be re-structured also to support SSO login.
Please Suggest .

Thanks

Comment: Do you need help with implementing SSO for your PHP application or for generating Metadata for you PHP application?

Comment: need to generate metadata for php application .

Comment: You can use this link to generate SP metadata: [https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php) You will need the SAML Endpoints of your PHP application to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to interact with a SAML IdP your application needs to play the role of a SAML SP (Service Provider). Using PHP you could have a look at https://simplesamlphp.org/samlsp